# {status} not available as variable in Solspace Rating:Entries?

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

Is {status} not an available variable in Rating:Entries?

It's a parameter but it doesn't seem to be available as a variable - I've tried using it in a conditional and it doesn't work.

Solspace, any comment? Any workaround?

I'm creating a page to show a logged in member's ratings but I want to show closed ratings and well as open ratings and display an extra "Pending approval" message on closed ratings only. Need status as a variable to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest versions of ExpressionEngine (2.6.x) and Rating (3.2.x), you can display the status of the rating submission by using the {rating_status} variable within the {exp:rating:entries} tag.

This was not documented for some reason, so I will be documenting it now. :)

Comment: Aha! I knew it must be there somewhere. I'll give it a try later today. Thanks.